# Neural network returns three class while it is actual 2

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

i would like to ask my  almost final question related to the previous questions :

there is problem description :

so i  have two category(dogs and cats), below i  have following code for  reading data into list and converting them to the array(numpy array)

it is for mounting  google drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True)
```

importing all necessary libraries(glob actually i dont need but  let stay)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
import glob
```

it is just demonstrating  of reading and displaying images for the future purpose

```
#Set main directory and also categories. read the images
MainDirectory ="/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/2020YearDeepLearning/Animals/PetImages/"
Categories =["Dog","Cat"]
for  category in Categories:
   path =os.path.join(MainDirectory,category)
   print(path)
   for img in os.listdir(path):
      img_array =cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
      plt.imshow(img_array,cmap="gray")
      plt.show()
      break
   break
```

Demonstration of  reshaping image

```
IMG_SIZE=70
img_array =cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
plt.imshow(img_array,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

now there is actual code which means to read  data and also labels(dogs and cat , dog is 0 and cat is 1) and putting them into array

```
#Create  a training Data
training_data =[]
for  category in Categories:
      path =os.path.join(MainDirectory,category)
      class_num =Categories.index(category)
      for img in os.listdir(path):
        try:
          img_array =cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
          img_array =cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
          training_data.append([img_array,class_num])
        except Exception as e:
          pass
```

after that one i just shuffled data

```
import random
random.shuffle(training_data)
```

separating data into X and y and convert to the numpy array with corresponding reshaping

```
X =[]
y =[]
for features,label in training_data:
  X.append(features)
  y.append(label)
X =np.array(X).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
y =np.array(y)
```

i would like to demonstrate  that there is only two possible value for y(dog is 0 and cat is 1 )

```
print(np.unique(y)) - which returns[0, 1]
```

now actual code

```
#create   simple convolutional neural network
#normalize data  and load all necessary  libraries
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Flatten,Conv2D,MaxPool2D,Activation
X =X/255.0
model =Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=32))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

i have trained data using following command

```
model.fit(X,y,batch_size=16,validation_split=0.1,epochs=10)
```

and here is image of training
[image]

after that , i took random picture of cat and dog and  run following command (this example i am using dog picture)

```
#for testing
image =cv2.imread("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/2020YearDeepLearning/Animals/test.jpg")
image =cv2.resize(image,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
image =np.array(image).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
print(model.predict_classes(image))
```

result is this one :
for  more details.

```
[[0]
 [0]
 [0]]
```

for cat i am getting this one

```
[[1]
 [0]
 [0]]
```

should i get result with three element? I mean array of three element? Actually i have two class right? please tell me if i am wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I suspect:

If your image is not gray, meaning it has three channels like a normal RBG image would have, then your resize here `image =np.array(image).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)` actually makes the returned image the shape `(3, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)`, which means that you actually feed in three samples each with 1 channel when you predict, and of course you will get back three results.

Plus, when you load image to train, you load with `grayscale`, but when you load for predicting, you forgot to do so. So this is why your training works but not predicting.

Comment: what about this line? img_array =cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  does not it convert to grayscale?

Comment: i see , i see so for the  final part right, let me change

Comment: @datodatuashvili yes it does, this is why your training works. But when you predict, you actually read a new image directly from the directory without coverting it to grayscale. This is why your predicting returns 3 answers

Comment: yes yes, now it is ok, [[0]] it is for first  case and [[1]] for second case

Comment: this is what i have changed : image =cv2.imread("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/2020YearDeepLearning/Animals/test.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

Comment: it solved, thanks very much and happy new year